# $pV$ work and Specific volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

I am working on a $pV$ work exercise.  I am given $P_1$, $P_2$, and $V_1$; we can solve for $V_2$.  I am also given mass.  I am told that the $pV$ relationship is $pv^{1.2}=const.$, where $v$ is specific volume, not Volume.
Integrating to find $pV$ work (using the $pV$ relationship) the solution disregards the specific volume in the expression and instead just uses "Volume".  I don't understand how this integral is evaluated in this sense. How did they arrive at what is in the denominator ($1 - 1.2$) ?
Third question: does the "constant" here equal to $p_1V_1^{1.2}$?
Thank You.

$$
p_1 = 160 lbf/in.^2\\
V_1 = 1ft^3\\
p_2 = 390 lbf/in.^2\\
pv^{1.2}= const.\\
V_2 = 0.4759 ft^3\\
m_{gas} = 0.4 lb\\
W = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} pdV = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{const}{V^{1.2}} dV = \frac{p_2V_2 - p_1V_1}{1-1.2}
$$

Comment: Nomenclature matters.  That should be "PV" work, not "pV" work.  In physics, upper case "P" is normally pressure, while lower case "p" is normally momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific volume is actually reciprocal of density or you can say the ratio of volume of a substance to mass of the substance. The mass would stay constant. Now you can work your way to the problem I'm sure.
For the second question[image]

3. the constant would equal to (P1)(V1/m)^1.2

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, do not post pictures. Type the question instead (and using MathJax for formulae).  There are many reasons, including facilitation for algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well.  Use a more formal language as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the mass (i.e., number of moles n) is constant, and, since nv=V, then$$Pv^{1.2}n^{1.2}=PV^{1.2}=Cn^{1.2}=C'$$where C' is another constant.

Answer (score 0):

> Integrating to find PV work (using the PV relationship) the solution
>   disregards the specific volume in the expression and instead just uses
>   "Volume". I don't understand how this integral is evaluated in this
>   sense.

Volume is used to calculate work. As Akash pointed out specific volume is volume divided by mass. You are given the mass, so multiply it by the specific volume gives volume.

> How did they arrive at what is in the denominator (1 minus 1.2) ?

It is a consequence of applying the following power rule where $n$ is not equal to -1

$$\int x^{n}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

In our case $n=-ϒ$

$$W=\int_{V_i}^{V_f}PdV$$

$$=\int_{V_i}^{V_f} \frac{k}{V^ϒ}dV$$

$$=\frac{k}{(1-ϒ)}\Biggl (\frac{1}{V^{ϒ-1}_{f}}-\frac{1}{V^{ϒ-1}_{i}}\Biggr)$$

Substituting

$$k=PV^ϒ$$

Gives

$$=\frac{1}{(1-ϒ)}\Biggl (\frac{P_{f}V_{f}^ϒ}{V^{ϒ-1}_{f}}-\frac{P_{f}V_{f}^ϒ}{V^{ϒ-1}_{i}}\Biggr)$$

and realizing

$$\frac{V^ϒ}{V^{ϒ-1}}=V$$

Gives the final expression

$$W=\frac{(P_{f}V_{f}-P_{i}V_{i})}{1-ϒ}$$

> Third question: does the "constant" here equal to (P1)(V1)^1.2 ?

Yes. And you use that fact to substitute for the constant (I call $k$ above) to get the final expression for work as shown above.

Hope this helps.